# Do you need multiple asynctask to run multiple task?

Tags: java, android

I under the basics of `AysncTask` and from my understanding, it should be used for small tasks that only take a few seconds.

So, I did the following:

```
 private class DbQueryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Long,Void,Void>{


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Long... id) {
            long longID = id[0];
            playerDatabase.delete(PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    _ID + "=" + longID,null);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

If I wanted to run another DB query in the background at, do I now have to create another subclass that extends asynctask, or can I create a new doInBackGround?

Because I feel that if I have to create another sub class, to perform another task, then I could be creating a ton of sub classes, surely there is a way under one sub class to create another doInBackground if called upon?

Thanks

Comment: if you want query simultaneously than use same  doInBackground else create another doInBackground and call in second doInBackground after first doInBackground completed.

Comment: `do I now have to create another subclass that extends asynctask,` yes

Comment: you can use loader class also

Comment: http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/03/android-simple-loadermanager-for.html

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders